# Force TLS renew on ingress

Tags: kubernetes

I have a subdomain that used to have a valid SSL certificate, but now it is falling

```
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - staging.mysite.com
    secretName: tls-cert
```

If I try to access I got the error

```
curl -vI https://staging.mysite.com/
*   Trying 35.10.156.13:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to staging.mysite.com (35.10.156.13) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.mycompany.com
*  start date: Mar 13 09:29:46 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Jun 11 09:29:45 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName does not match staging.mysite.com
* SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'staging.mysite.com'
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'staging.mysite.com'
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

...
```

Is there some way to force the regeneration of the TLS certificates of this ingress?

This ingress is on a namespace

I tried `cmctl`, but it seems to work at the cluster, in my case is just one Ingress.

Comment: The error message indicates wrong configuration, not expiration.

Comment: What I can do to solve this?

Comment: Deploy a new one with correct configuration. I don't know how to do this for you. Nobody is able to look into your infrastructure without telepathy skills.

Comment: Did the connection to `https://staging.mysite.com/` configured with the Ingress controller work before without problems?